# Refactoring Perl code on a live Web site. Are mutual module dependencies OK?

Tags: perl, recursion, refactoring

We have a big Perl based Web site.

I am assigned to refactor code of many scripts and packages. Sometimes changes are easy and I just modify existing functions. But sometimes I need to rewrite entire functions. The bad news that the functions which I rewrite call other functions. So if I move refactored code in my new module I need also copy all supplementary functions. But if I do not move refactored code to my special module, a tiny syntax error may crash the entire site :-(

Yes, I know we should use version control, etc. But we don't and this is a fact which I can't change. What to do?

So I need to keep some code in a Test module (to avoid syntax errors to crash the entire site). Would it be OK to make circular references from other modules to Test (for my new refactored routines) and from Test to other modules (for supplemetary routines)?

Note that we have some `AutoRequire` module which is required by most of our scripts and modules. `AutoRequire` makes A::X() call to automatically load A module (if it is not yet loaded).

My main question is whether it is OK in this settings to use mutual module dependencies. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Even if your company doesn't use version control, you can use it locally to keep track of the changes *you* make so they're easy to revert. Also, consider writing some [tests](http://qa.perl.org/testing/) for your application so you can tell when a change will introduce a regression or otherwise break something.

Comment: And would it be that hard to set up another instance of the site for testing purposes? Making untested changes to a live production site is just asking for trouble.

Comment: It can get tricky if one imports from the other, one uses constants from the other, or one uses prototypes. OO modules tend to do less of this, so you're less likely to have problems with those.

Answer (score 1):

Require works by first checking if the module is already loaded and if not load it and afterwards mark it as loaded. So if you have a dependency that Foo requires Bar and Bar requires Foo it will first try to load Foo, within Foo try to load Bar. But because Bar requires Foo and Bar was not yet finally loaded this can give problems.

Edit after input from @ysth: it will not fail but it might load some thing only partially, which might cause interesting problems later.

So it might just work, but it also might give problems later (like failing to use exported functions or so).

Comment: no, it won't fail (did you try it?).  but one of the modules will be only partly loaded during the running of the top-level code in the other, which can cause interesting errors.

Comment: avoid using B.pm as an example module name, since there is a core module of that name.

Answer (score 0):

Perl allows mutual dependencies, but they can sometimes lead to unintuitive behaviour. An example I've [given before](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1077158) is:

**foo.pm**

```
package foo;
use bar;
sub import { printf("%s loaded foo\n", scalar caller) }
1;
```

**bar.pm**

```
package bar;
use foo;
sub import { printf("%s loaded bar\n", scalar caller) }
1;
```

**script.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
package main;
use foo;
```

Output:

```
foo loaded bar
main loaded foo
```

Didn't you expect to see `bar loaded foo` somewhere in that output?

With careful consideration of compile time versus runtime, etc, etc, you'll realise why that line was not output, and that this is proper and documented behaviour. Just not necessarily very intuitive.

That said, for purely object-oriented modules which don't do anything on import (e.g. export anything to their caller, or act as a pragma, or—as in this example—print output), it should generally be pretty safe.

That said, for purely object-oriented modules there's usually no reason to load them upfront with `use` anyway—instead you can load them with `require` or [Module::Runtime](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aRuntime) when they are needed.